# Check if URL parameter exist in comma separated values in php

Tags: php

I want to check if URL parameter exist from a series of comma seprated values. I have some code for this, that is,

```html
$matchFound = (isset($_GET["id"]) && trim($_GET["id"]) == $urlval);
$slide = $matchFound ? trim($_GET["id"]) : '';
```

Now if $urlval = 12 and my URL is this- example website.com/test/?id=12 then the above code is working perfectly.
But I want a code that can work even if $urlval = 10,11,12,13 and URL is- website.com/test/?id=12

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just `explode()` your $urlval and use `in_array()` - this will work even when $urlval is a single value

```
$matchFound = isset($_GET["id"]) && in_array($_GET["id"], explode(",",$urlval));
$slide = $matchFound ? trim($_GET["id"]) : '';
```